# netcat producing EINVAL when sending to UDP IPv6 multicast

Tags: ipv6, socket, netcat, multicast

I'm using netcat on Fedora to test an IPv6 UDP multi-cast address.  The command is

```bsh
echo hi | nc -6 -u ff02::777:777:777 7777
```

netcat responds, "Invalid argument."

Running strace yields

```c
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(7777), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "ff02::777:777:777", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINVAL
```

Running a similar command but without the IPv6,

```bsh
echo hi | nc -u 192.168.255.255 7777
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminary note: your IPv4 network is not set up as 192.168.0.0/16 but most probably as 192.168.0.0/24 or any other /24 range: 192.168.255.255 is thus not a broadcast, else `echo hi | nc -u 192.168.255.255 7777` would have failed. For broadcast, not supported with IPv6 but only with IPv4, an application must use the `SO_BROADCAST` socket option. This is achieved with the `-b` option for netcat. Assuming you are actually in network 192.168.0.0/24 (not /16), that would be:

```
nc -b -u 192.168.0.255 7777
```

Note that broadcast is not multicast.

---

About the question. The entire `ff02::/16` range is within the *link-local* multicast scope. For this scope an address is complete only when an interface is associated to it (that's why it's a **link**-local scope). A valid address in this range can't be only `ff02::777:777:777`.  Assuming that the LAN interface is called `eth0`,`ff02::777:777:777%eth0` is a valid address, as defined in [RFC 4007](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4007#section-11):

```
nc -6 -u ff02::777:777:777%eth0 7777
```

This is probably automatically handled by libraries rather than by the `nc` command itself. Using a scope not requiring an interface will usually fail because then the interface should not be part of the address.

If you don't want to have to need the interface, don't use the link-local (nor node-local) scope(s). Switch to site-local: ff05 which doesn't require specifying an interface to work:

```
nc -6 -u ff05::777:777:777 7777
```

---

On Linux the distinction can be seen for these two commands with `ss`:

```
$ ss -aun dport == 7777
State  Recv-Q  Send-Q                     Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port
ESTAB  0       0           [2001:db8:900d:cafe:0:1:2:3]:58092  [ff05::777:777:777]:7777        
ESTAB  0       0       [fe80::8c5f:87ff:fe50:d08a]%eth0:60937  [ff02::777:777:777]:7777
```

Here as a global address is available on *eth0* and it's not a link-local scope, this address was chosen as source. For the link-local scoped address, the socket is bound to the interface. For the Linux case, see this Q/A for other caveats related to the choice of the interface when sending (and having not used `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF`): [How to set preferred IPv6 interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663641/how-to-set-preferred-ipv6-interface)

---

Final note: you should consider switching to [*socat*](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) with much more features than *netcat*, including [joining multicast groups *for IPv4*](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html). While it supports IPv6 it doesn't directly support IPv6 multicast but can use arbitrary `setsockopt(2)` calls for unsupported features, including handling IPv6 multicast. That's still better than *netcat* which just has no support to receive multicast traffic emitted by the previous *netcat* commands.

So with *socat*, here's an example valid at least on Linux with amd64 (x86_64) architecture and possibly working on other *nix possibly after changing the value 20 below with its adequate replacement (for `IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`/`IPV6_JOIN_GROUP`), using a raw `setsockopt(2)` option to enable receiving the multicast traffic on the interface with index 2 (the first interface after *lo*), sent by the first *netcat* command:

```
socat udp6-recv:7777,setsockopt-listen=41:20:xff020000000000000000077707770777i2 -
```

The option would be decoded like this using `strace`:

```
setsockopt(5, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, {inet_pton(AF_INET6, "ff02::777:777:777", &ipv6mr_multiaddr), ipv6mr_interface=if_nametoindex("eth0")}, 20) = 0
```

The so-called "dalan" format for passing arbitrary socket options is used here for an *ipv6_mreq* structure: one IPv6 address (`x` for arbitrary hex values, here 16 bytes for the IPv6 address) followed by one interface index (`i` for an integer).