# ipv6 multicast fails when it should loop back to self

Tags: ipv6, netcat, multicast, loopback

So far I use multicast with ipv4 and it works; all involved computers run linux. I listen on two machines and send on one of those two (in a separate terminal). In the below example 'Hello 1' is received on the sending machine (strawberry) and on the remote machine (ero).

```
ero:~$ sudo ip addr add 224.4.19.42 dev enp4s0 autojoin
ero:~$ netcat -l -k -u -p 9988

strawberry:~ $ sudo ip addr add 224.4.19.42 dev wlan0 autojoin
strawberry:~ $ netcat -l -k -u -p 9988

strawberry:~ $ echo "Hello 1" | netcat -s 192.168.178.109 -w 0 -u 224.4.19.42 9988
```

With ipv6 it works as long as only remote machines listen; 'Hello 2' in the below example is received by ero. Once the sender (strawberry) has also joined the multicast group, neither the sender (strawberry) nor the remote machine (ero) receives 'Hello 3':

```
ero:~$ sudo ip addr add ff05:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:4141 dev enp4s0 autojoin
ero:~$ netcat -l -k -u -p 9988

strawberry:~ $ echo "Hello 2" | netcat -w 0 -s 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:76d0 -u ff05:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:4141 9988

strawberry:~ $ sudo ip addr add ff05:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:4141 dev wlan0 autojoin
strawberry:~ $ netcat -l -k -u -p 9988

strawberry:~ $ echo "Hello 3" | netcat -w 0 -s 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:76d0 -u ff05:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:4141 9988
```

Maybe of interest: when I do not provide a sender address, i.e., no -s option, then the ipv4 example shows the same behaviour as ipv6: message only received as long as strawberry has not joined the multicast group. Thus I tried different sending addresses with ipv6: the global address shown in the example (2001:...), a unique local address (ULA; fd00:...) and a link-local address (LLA; fe80:...). Neither helps.

Any hints what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should not add an IP multicast address to an interface. You should have an application using the correct API to join multicast groups and/or enable the socket option to received looped back multicast traffic. netcat can do neither of these. socat can do both for IPv4 and can also do this for IPv6 by using an hand crafted parameter for the correct IPv6 multicast setsockopt syscall since it appears it doesn't support it with a "native" option.

Comment: @A.B. Great, thanks for pointing this out. It works well for ipv4 (receiving end: `socat UDP4-RECV:9988,ip-add-membership=224.42.42.42:192.168.178.109 - ` ; still using netcat to send). I need to do some more reading for the _hand crafted parameter for the correct IPv6 multicast setsockopt syscall_ .

Comment: Here's an example in an answer of mine for the IPv6 part: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656582/netcat-producing-einval-when-sending-to-udp-ipv6-multicast/664826#664826

Comment: Great. Your example from the other thread works perfectly. Many thanks.For other readers: needs a recent socat version else option `setsockopt-listen` is missing (1.7.3.2 on debian buster is too old, but 1.7.4.1 works and all dependencies are fulfilled on an updated buster, so the socat binary can be simply copied). And also site-local multicast addresses `[ff05:...]` require to add an interface, i.e., i2 or i3 or so.

Comment: @A.B If you copy your comment to an answer, I am more than happy to give you credit by marking the question as solved.

Comment: Just found that part of the support is implemented in socat but not documented, while other part is not implemented and also probably requires to be specified using raw/dalan socket options (because using netcat will be unreliable). Will take some time.

Comment: So now I made a proper (and not just comment) answer, did you test it?

Comment: Many thanks. I have tested the version with setsockopt-listen; works very well. The socat version in Debian oldoldstable does not have this option, but I could easily manually download a newer version; all dependencies as per deb package were fulfilled even with oldoldstable.

Comment: The current answer doesn't require setsockopt-listen at all.

Comment: Understood and agreed. My previous comment was maybe too short: I have tried your original version (with setsockopt-listen) and to do this I had downloaded a newer socat version. I have not yet tried your updated version using the undocumented `ipv6-add-membership`. I will do this later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

For a host system, while sending to a multicast IP address is quite similar to sending to an unicast address, receiving multicast is different and uses additional APIs: an host doesn't assign a multicast address to an interface, instead it joins multicast addresses of interest to receive select multicast traffic when an application (using a socket) on it requests it. This is [described in RFC 1112](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1112#section-7). The RFC's *JoinHostGroup* and *LeaveHostGroup* functions are transposed on the BSD socket API used by most *nix by the use of [`setsockopt(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/setsockopt.2) options to join and leave multicast groups. IPv6 follows this just as IPv4 but there are differences (including in routing behavior). POSIX even describes in a [few](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_20_04) [places](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) how should be implemented the IPv6 API (it doesn't appear to describe IPv4's multicast so much, perhaps because it's a bit more fragmented among OSes and thus not worth it).

On Linux, the main socket options used are [`IP_MULTICAST_IF`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ip.7#IP_MULTICAST_IF) plus [`IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ip.7#IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP) for IPv4 and [`IPV6_MULTICAST_IF`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ipv6.7#IPV6_MULTICAST_IF) plus [`IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ipv6.7#IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,) (with an alias of `IPV6_JOIN_GROUP` to follow POSIX) for IPv6. Also of interest to OP's question, but enabled by default: [`IP_MULTICAST_LOOP`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ip.7#IP_MULTICAST_LOOP) and [`IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ipv6.7#IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP).

Knowing what happens on the wire to have this work inside a network ([IGMP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3376) for IPv4 or [MLD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3810) for IPv6...) or across networks (for example using [PIM-SM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7761.html)) isn't needed at the application level (but could be needed to troubleshoot problems, especially those involving switches and multicast snooping).

The remaining answer expects that no special tinkering to network configuration was done on the systems: no multicast address added to any interface and no `autojoin` option. Note also that 224.4.19.42 belongs to an [AD-HOC Block II block assigned to the London Stock exchange](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#multicast-addresses-6). Private [Organization-Local Scope blocks](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#multicast-addresses-12) can be picked [within 239.0.0.0/8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2365.html).

## *netcat*

*netcat* (all of its [variants](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457670/netcat-how-to-listen-on-a-tcp-port-using-ipv6-address/457685#457685)) doesn't handle multicast. So while by tweaking the network settings (*autojoin* is normally intended to be used along configurations involving tunnels) OP managed to use netcat with IPv4 multicast addresses but not IPv6 anyway, any application actually using multicast follows the standards and uses the additional APIs for proper multicast support. A diagnostic tool such as *netcat* is used to replace a more complex software, but this replacement should be able to do the same: *netcat* won't.

## [*socat*](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)

### IPv4

*socat* has (almost) complete [IPv4 multicast support](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html).

The way to send to such multicast group is by stating through which multicast-enabled interface it should be sent through (actually *socat* only appears to support the address variant of this API, so an interface can't be provided when using *socat* while the API supports it, unless using [dalan](https://manpages.debian.org/socat/socat.1#data) raw `setsockopt` socat option, see below) and optionally by stating if multicast loopback is required (it's enabled by default so useless here, so I'll put it in only one example):

On strawberry, if a default route exists or at least a route to multicast 224.4.19.42 using the expected interface is present, then simply this is enough (the first command doesn't require any multicast-related feature, so that's the only case that `nc` can also be used for):

```
echo "Hello 1" | socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.4.19.42:9988
echo "Hello 1" | socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.4.19.42:9988,ip-multicast-loop=1
```

else the interface has to be specified by an address on it:

```
echo "Hello 1" | socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.4.19.42:9988,ip-multicast-if=192.168.178.109
```

Using the documented [dalan](https://manpages.debian.org/socat/socat.1#data) format one can use arbitrary socket options in `socat` using its `setsockopt` option for the unsupported part of the API described in Introduction paragraph. It is OS and can be architecture dependent. Here it will be about Linux (>= 3.5) on amd64 (x86_64) architecture.

[`SOL_IP`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/socket.h?h=v6.1#n339) = 0
[`IP_MULTICAST_IF`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/in.h?h=v6.1#n146) = 32

expected alternate structure for an `in_mreq` variant of the API: one IPv4 multicast address (4 bytes in hex for the IPv4 address in big endian format, introduced by a leading `x`) plus one local address (4 more bytes). For an `in_mreqn` variant: same plus also one index of integer size introduced by a leading `i`. Not all parameters must be filled in. Working examples (using JSON format and the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) command to compute the interface index from `wlan0`):

```
echo "Hello 1" | socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.4.19.42:9988,setsockopt=0:32:x00000000xc0a8b26d
echo "Hello 1" | socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.4.19.42:9988,setsockopt=0:32:x00000000x00000000i$(ip -j link show enp4s0 | jq '.[].ifindex')
```

If using `ip-multicast-loop=0`, then strawberry will not receive its own emitted multicast traffic.

The receiving part has to use `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` to specify the multicast IP address group to join, and optionally a local address or an interface if one doesn't want to rely on the routing stack to pick the correct choice (again one of these options is needed if there is no correct route to the multicast address, for example if there is no default route or if the default is wrong). Stating this local address shouldn't be needed either when the socket is bound to an address other than `INADDR_ANY` since then the OS will follow this choice.
The receiving part can use `UDP4-RECV` (to merge what is received) or `UDP4-RECVFROM` (to split on each datagram) usually along a `fork` option. For example:

If there is a route (incl. default) for 224.4.19.42, then on both hosts:

```
socat -u UDP4-RECV:9988,ip-add-membership=224.4.19.42:0.0.0.0 -
```

Else (here choosing the interface name syntax),

- for *strawberry*:

  ```
  socat -u UDP4-RECV:9988,ip-add-membership=224.4.19.42:wlan0 -
  ```
- for *ero*:

  ```
  socat -u UDP4-RECV:9988,ip-add-membership=224.4.19.42:enp4s0 -
  ```

### IPv6

It appears IPv6 support was partially implemented: similar to `ip-add-membership` for IPv4, the equivalent option `ipv6-add-membership` does exist in sources and works but is not documented anywhere. All tests were made with [socat 7.4.1](https://repo.or.cz/socat.git/tree/refs/tags/tag-1.7.4.1) so showing this release. The [option exists](https://repo.or.cz/socat.git/blob/refs/tags/tag-1.7.4.1:/xioopts.c#l786):

```c
#ifdef IPV6_JOIN_GROUP
        IF_IP6    ("ipv6-add-membership",       &opt_ipv6_join_group)
#endif
```

or an alias:

```c
#ifdef IPV6_JOIN_GROUP
        IF_IP6    ("ipv6-join-group",   &opt_ipv6_join_group)
#endif
```

with the [format declaration](https://repo.or.cz/socat.git/blob/refs/tags/tag-1.7.4.1:/xio-ip6.c#l25) for using `setsockopt(2)` later:

```c
#ifdef IPV6_JOIN_GROUP
const struct optdesc opt_ipv6_join_group = { "ipv6-join-group", "join-group", OPT_IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, GROUP_SOCK_IP6, PH_PASTSOCKET, TYPE_IP_MREQN, OFUNC_SOCKOPT, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_JOIN_GROUP };
#endif
```

So basic listening to multicast IPv6 is actually supported (else this would require a dalan `setsockopt-listen` *socat* option which requires a recent version). Choosing to send not using the default routing stack's choice isn't natively possible because there is no `ipv6-multicast-if` option (yet?). It's still available with the dalan format. The structure used for `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF` requires only an interface index. Using `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF` is probably always required if the IPv6 multicast scope is below site-local (eg: ff01::/16 or ff02::/16) but is often required for other cases too (see below). Likewise, the parameter `ipv6-multicast-loop` has not been implemented so also requires a dalan format setsockopt option.

IPv6 routing behavior differs slightly from IPv4 here. It might not follow the default route and might have undefined behavior on a system using multiple interface where routes have not be explicitly defined, depending on the order the interfaces are (re)configured: the routing table could switch from:

```
# ip -6 route show table all type multicast
multicast ff00::/8 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev dummy0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

to

```
# ip -6 route show table all type multicast
multicast ff00::/8 dev dummy0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

just because an interface went down then up, changing the default interface to be used. Running any kind of container, VM or dynamic interface could lead to this.

In the end, just sending blindly trusting the system's routing stack choice (or if routes are known to be configured correctly) on *strawberry* (mind the quotes to avoid the shell interpreting brackets needed for IPv6):

```
echo "Hello 1" | socat -u - UDP6-DATAGRAM:'[ff05::4141]':9988
```

Specifying an interface to send through and explicitly stating to use multicast loopback requires dalan format `setsockopt` option:

[`SOL_IPV6`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/socket.h?h=v6.1#n343) = 41
[`IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/in.h?h=v6.1#n148) = 19
[`IPV6_MULTICAST_IF`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/in6.h?h=v6.1#n169) = 17
`IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP`'s boolean: actually integer (hence the letter `i` used in dalan data format)
`IPV6_MULTICAST_IF`'s index: integer

```
echo "Hello 1" | socat -u - UDP6-DATAGRAM:'[ff05::4141]':9988,setsockopt=41:19:i1,setsockopt=41:17:i$(ip -j link show wlan0 | jq '.[].ifindex')
```

- receiving on *strawberry*:

  ```
  socat -u UDP6-RECV:9988,ipv6-add-membership='[ff05::4141]':wlan0 -
  ```
- likewise receiving on *ero*:

  ```
  socat -u UDP6-RECV:9988,ipv6-add-membership='[ff05::4141]':enp4s0 -
  ```

IPv6 multicast communication between an arbitrary number of peers is possible. Here's an example, while disabling receiving its own looped back multicast traffic and specifying the interface:

- *strawberry*:

  ```
  socat UDP6-DATAGRAM:'[ff05::4141]':9988,bind=:9988,ipv6-add-membership='[ff05::4141]':wlan0,setsockopt=41:19:i0,setsockopt=41:17:i$(ip -j link show wlan0 | jq '.[].ifindex') -
  ```
- *ero* (same, only the interface name chances):

  ```
  socat UDP6-DATAGRAM:'[ff05::4141]':9988,bind=:9988,ipv6-add-membership='[ff05::4141]':enp4s0,setsockopt=41:19:i0,setsockopt=41:17:i$(ip -j link show enp4s0 | jq '.[].ifindex') -
  ```
- additional systems can run the same command too, only the interface name will possibly differ.

Each `socat` will send data (typed on the terminal) to all other multicast peers and will also read back traffic sent from them (but not from itself).